# "ER_PARSE_ERROR" error during mysql query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Here's the code:

```
SELECT * FROM gallery LIMIT " + limit + " OFFSET " + offset + " ORDER BY gid DESC
```

This gives:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `ORDER BY gid DESC` at line 1

What's wrong with my code ?

PS:

```
var limit = 8;
var offset = ((Number(req.query.page)-1)*limit) || 0 ;
```

It works without `ORDER BY gid DESC`
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the documentation on [`SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) when composing queries. It's very specific about the order things have to be in.

`ORDER BY` comes before `LIMIT`.

Comment: Easy mistake to make. That's why I have the MySQL documentation bookmarked.